# Set as Desktop Background is missing

Tags: system

The <kbd>Set as Desktop Background</kbd> option is missing. It was available after installation but now this has disappeared...?

Why has this happened and how can we get this pre-installed feature back...?

Comment: I have the same issue ! ando many poeple too...

Comment: This is a bug, a fix was issued about an hour ago. For future reference, please report bugs to bugs.launchpad.net/elementary

Comment: Yeah, run software updater, the issue is solved in 0.3.2

Answer (score 3):

## Update

An update has been released to address this issue within Freya. If you are running Freya, please update. If you are not yet running Freya, please upgrade.